# Integrating the log logistic density

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, closed-form

I want to integrate the density of the log logistic distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution). The Wikipedia article already tells us (from the expected value) that -

\begin{equation}\int_0^\infty x.\frac{\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^{\beta - 1}}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)^2} = \frac{\alpha \pi}{\beta sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\beta}\right)}\end{equation}

What I want to find is -

$$\int_0^t x.\frac{\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^{\beta - 1}}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)^2}dx$$

I tried to use integration by parts, observing that -

$$\frac{-\beta. x^{\beta-1}}{\alpha^\beta(1+\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)} = d\left(\frac{1}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)^2}\right)$$

So,

$$\int_0^t x.\frac{\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^{\beta - 1}}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)^2}dx = -\int_0^t d\left(\frac{1}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)^2}\right).x$$

$$ = -\left[\frac{x}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)}\right]_0^t + \int_0^t \frac{dx}{(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta)}$$

Now, I'm stuck on the second part of the above integral. We know that as $t \to \infty$ it becomes the expected value (since the first part then becomes $0$). But is there a closed form for the bounded integral as well? If not, is there a good numerical way to solve it?

Comment: Using the change of variable $u=(x/\alpha)^\beta$ and $s=(t/\alpha)^\beta$, and then the change of variable $z=s/(1+s)$ and $v=u/(1+u)$, this is $$\int_0^s\frac{\alpha u^{1/\beta}du}{(1+u)^2}=\alpha\int_0^zv^{1/\beta}(1-v)^{-1/\beta}dv=\alpha\,\mathrm{B}(z;1+1/\beta,1-1/\beta)$$ where $\mathrm{B}$ denotes the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), thus, ...

Comment: $$\int_0^t x\,\frac{\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^{\beta - 1}}{\left(1 + \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)^\beta\right)^2}\,dx=\alpha\,\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{t^\beta}{\alpha^\beta+t^\beta};1+\frac1\beta,1-\frac1\beta\right)$$ Not sure that all this is more than a mere rewriting of the original formula though.

Comment: Thanks! That should have been an answer :)

Comment: Also, its a little surprising that as $t \to \infty$ we get the nice closed form. I would expect the Beta function. Or are they the same?

Comment: When $t\to\infty$, $$\frac{t^\beta}{\alpha^\beta+t^\beta}\to1$$ hence the limit of the RHS is $$\alpha\,\mathrm{B}\left(1+\frac1\beta,1-\frac1\beta\right)=\alpha\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac1\beta\right)\,\Gamma\left(1-\frac1\beta\right)=\alpha\,\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}$$ where we used [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) for the Gamma function.